# How can I disable the email verification on reset password using Azure AD B2C?

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How can I disable the email verification on reset password using Azure AD B2C?

I want to skip the email verification on the reset password user journey and instead I want to make an API call to my own API before allowing the user to define I new password.

Note: I am using custom policies.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

"PasswordReset" calls "LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress".

That has:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
```

The "Verified.Email" is the piece that kicks off the validation.

Remove it and call your [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-intro) as another step in the user journey.

The actual password functionality is done by the next step "LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId".